# Galaxy S4 SCH-I545 stuck in Start Up Failed

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader

After using the Official TWRP app to flash TWRP recovery to my Samsung Galaxy S4, I am stuck on a screen that says "Start-Up Failed" and "Secure Fail: Kernel." I think it is because I flashed it to both Recovery and Boot. Do anyone know how to get out of the screen? It does not matter if the phone is completely wiped.